# @ViewChild for Multiple Layers of Views

Tags: angular, typescript

### Overview

In Angular 2 with TypeScript, is it possible to use `@ViewChild(__component__)` to select a child component of a child component? If not, is there a better option?

### Context

I have created a Jasmine test for my component, and can successfully use `@ViewChild(MyComponent)` to select the component to test, but I need to select a child of the component I'm testing.

### Existing Attempts

Currently I have simply added the annotation `@ViewChild(DeeperComponent)` on a variable in the test component, but this has produced `null`. However, I have **successfully** selected the child's child component by adding the `@ViewChild(DeeperComponent)` in the component I'm testing (the child, `MyComponent`), but this is not the ideal solution, since I am not using the `DeeperComponent` (child's child) directly in the `ts` file of the child (`MyComponent`).

Comment: Did you try to get the value in ngAfterViewInit() hook ?

Comment: no, that's not possible. check this article https://vsavkin.com/three-ways-to-test-angular-2-components-dcea8e90bd8d, maybe it will give you some ideas